# Prove that any collection of vectors that includes zero vector can’t be linearly independent.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors

I am stuck at the first step which is the definition of linear independence, that is, vectors $v_1, v_2, ......, v_k$ are linearly independent if and only if there exist scalars $c_1,c_2,.....c_k$ such that
$ c_1v_1 + c_2v_2+ .......+ c_kv_k= 0 $ implying $ c_1=c_2=c_3=....=c_k=0.$

Now how do I proceed to prove the question about zero vector? The only thing I can think of is that with a zero vector it becomes impossible to prove that scalar multiplied with it is zero.
Please help.

Comment: check the definition of linearly independent

Comment: Is there something wrong with the definition?

Comment: linearly independent means $c_1v_1+c_2v_2+\cdots+c_kv_k=0\implies c_1=c_2=\cdots=c_k=0$; linearly dependent means there exist scalars $c_1,c_2,...,c_k$ , not all zero, such that $c_1v_1+c_2v_2+\cdots+c_kv_k=0$

Comment: I wrote the same definition????

Comment: no, there exist scalars is part of my linearly *dependent* definition; for linear *in*dependence, there *do not* exist scalars, not all $0$ (i.e., for *all * scalars, if $c_1v_1+\cdots=0$, then $c_1=...=0$)

Answer (score 1):

Linearly independent means

$c_1v_1+c_2v_2+\cdots c_iv_i+\cdots+c_kv_k=0\implies c_1=c_2=\cdots=c_k=0$.

But if $v_i=0$, then we have $0v_1+0v_2+\cdots+5v_i+\cdots+0v_k=0$.

Comment: So I am right in the edit I made to the body of the question.

Comment: the part you added at the end is okay, but I'd still quibble with your definition